# Matplotlib plot stopped updating in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working on this application which involves plotting a line or circle on an empty plot after pressing a button. It was all well until suddenly, the graph just stopped updating. For example:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, cos, tan, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
# Initialising the graph
f = Figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

root = tk.Tk()

class Application(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.pack()
    self.mainwindow()

  def mainwindow(self):
    self.add_loci = Button(self)
    self.add_loci["text"] = "Add Line"
    self.add_loci["command"] = self.line
    self.add_loci.pack(side = TOP)

    # Plotting an empty graph
    a.set_xlabel('Re')
    a.set_ylabel('Im')
    a.grid(b=None)
    a.plot(0, 0)
    # Setting up and showing the toolbar and the graph
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

  def line(self):
    a.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])
    print('test')

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

[image: Image of the Test GUI]

The supposed outcome when pressing the button is that a straight should appear, but it doesn't. I added the print statement to check if the button is working correctly and it does, so I really don't know what the problem here is. I'm currently using Spyder (3.2.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working, i.e. the line is being plotted, however the figure needs to be updated. You can do this using `figure.canvas.draw()` after your plot. Your code would look something like:

```
f = Figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

root = tk.Tk()

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.mainwindow()

    def mainwindow(self):
        self.add_loci = Button(self)
        self.add_loci["text"] = "Add Line"
        self.add_loci["command"] = self.line
        self.add_loci.pack(side = TOP)

        # Plotting an empty graph
        a.set_xlabel('Re')
        a.set_ylabel('Im')
        a.grid(b=None)
        a.plot(0, 0)
        # Setting up and showing the toolbar and the graph
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def line(self):

        a.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])
        f.canvas.draw()

        print('test')

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

You could also make the canvas you create an instance variable, by using `self.canvas = ...`. Then using `self.canvas.draw()`. Your `mainwindow` and `line` function would then look like:

```
def mainwindow(self):
    self.add_loci = Button(self)
    self.add_loci["text"] = "Add Line"
    self.add_loci["command"] = self.line
    self.add_loci.pack(side = TOP)

    # Plotting an empty graph
    a.set_xlabel('Re')
    a.set_ylabel('Im')
    a.grid(b=None)
    a.plot(0, 0)
    # Setting up and showing the toolbar and the graph
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, root)
    toolbar.update()
    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def line(self):

    a.plot([0, 10], [0, 10])
    self.canvas.draw()

    print('test')
```

Both would produce the same result.